# Lua socket: why doesn't socket.http.request download entire html code of a page?

Tags: http, lua

I want to download to a Lua string the entire html code of [this web page](http://magiccards.info/roe/en/4.html). The problem is that the saved code skips some lines that are visible on Google Chrome when I use Inspect Elements command (right click on webpage, last option).

I need that lines because I want to use the informations written there, to be precise I want to catch the card prices.

The code used is simply:

```
-- loads the HTTP module and any libraries it requires
local http  = require("socket.http")

-- Lua socket --
b, c, h = http.request("http://magiccards.info/roe/en/4.html")
print(b)
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Probably some of the elements on the page are created after the main document loads, either by Javascript DOM operations, or AJAX queries which fill up the missing parts. You could look if these scripts are indeed downloaded and then run them locally using some embedded engine like V8.

Comment: Well, it will certainly be a lot more complicated. Maybe **Node.js** has some plugins for that.

Comment: I am not an expert at this topic, unfortunately. However, if you only want to get this one site, you could identify all the missing elements "by hand", and then hardcode the corresponding requests to fetch missing parts, I guess.

Comment: well... I have a list of cards ( and so of websites) where I have to do that!

Comment: Why not simply link directly to the price site which is http://magic.tcgplayer.com/db/magic_single_card.asp?cn=Emrakul,%20the%20Aeons%20Torn&partner=MAGCINFO

Comment: First, a little explanation: every Magic cards has a number like, for example, 134/158. It means it is the 134th card of the particular set formed by 158 cards in total.

The magiccards.info website, the string to the card website is very well structured because it is formed this way: www.magiccards.info/<set name>/<language>/<card number>.html

Now, on my PC I have a file where a table is written with all these references, so the idea is to load it in Lua and use it to write the web site string, search for the prices and save them on another table.
On magic.tcgplayer.com, I can't do it.

Comment: You could if you use the first page to extract the link for the second page and then get the data from there.

Comment: this is the script that generates that table: http://partner.tcgplayer.com/x2/mcpl.ashx?pk=MAGCINFO&sid=34698

you'll have to see if there is some web service you can hit to get the information you wish to get.